# How do I separate 4.8 and meters from 4.8meters in C

Tags: c

I have `4.8meters`
I want to put `4.8` in a `float` variable and `meters` in string.
I wanted to do it using `strtok()` but wasn't able to.

Comment: You can't do this with `strtok()`, it only works when you have delimiters between the tokens, not when the delimiters are included with the token.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Why would you want to use `strtok`? It is used to split strings into tokens based on delimiters. You don't have any useful delimiter. Also, `strtok` would replace the delimiter with a `\0` byte. You don't have room for that.

Comment: Use `strspn()` to match the initial sequence of digits and decimal point.

Comment: You need to show some code. With almost no information, the only thing we can say is you did something wrong.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Using strtok for this is wrong to begin with.

Comment: You should take a look at [strtod](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtod.3p.html)

Comment: You could use [`strtof`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtof/).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `strtod` to parse the floating point number and set a pointer to the rest of the string:

```
      char str[] = "4.8meters";
      char *p;
      double x = strtod(str, &p);

      if (p == str) {
          printf("error: no number to parse\n");
      } else {
          printf("x=%f  unit=%s\n", x, p);
      }
```

Output: `x=4.800000  unit=meters`

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this sort of thing is with `sscanf`:

```
char *str = "4.8meters";
float f;
char unit[10];

int n = sscanf(str, "%f%9s", &f, unit);

if(n == 2)
     printf("number: %f, unit: %s\n", f, unit);
else if(n == 1)
     printf("number: %f (no unit)\n", f);
else printf("invalid input\n");
```

A couple things to note here:

1. As for any member of the scanf family, it's vital to check the return value, to see if all expected items were parsed.  In this case, the code is written so that it can tolerate the case where the unit string is missing.
2. As it happens, using `scanf` in this way, it will equally accept `"4.8meters"` or `"4.8 meters"` — that is, whitespace is optional between the number and the string.
3. There's a limit on how long the unit string can be -— in this case, 9 characters.